Displaying feature's symbology when feature is not in QGIS Map View
I have a point layer with some symbology that is much bigger than the points (the extent of map sheets for an atlas). If you look at a section of the map where the point feature is not in view but the symbology should be the sheet boundaries disappear. The sheet boundaries are created using the Geometry Generator which responds to the page size and scale of the map, so they need to be dynamic.
Is there a way to force the symbology for features to render even if the features are off-screen?


Nope. You could use polygons and update their geometry using expressions before exporting the map.

@Erik This layer is used for setting up the sheets so needs to be dynamic, so that users can see the impact of changing scales or map sizes.

Depending on your use case this built-in functionality may work for you : https://docs.qgis.org/3.40/en/docs/user_manual/map_views/map_view.html#layoutextents-decoration

not sure if this is doable in this case but using a virtual layer with an expression to create the sheet boundary geometry rather than using geometry generator wont have the problem of not displaying if the point is not in view

@J.R That's a useful feature I didn't know about but sadly only shows the active page of an atlas not all the pages - still handy

@J.R not sure if I can get the map item size and scale in an SQL query - currently done with a custom function so if I can execute that its just a case of how frequently a virtual layer gets re-drawn/ calculated
